# How to select some items from a List and use like a string Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a method which returns a list from a WebService :

```
private void Cliente_AlunoRetrieveCompleted(object sender, AlunoRetrieveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lbLista.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}
```

Where lbLista is my ListBox :

```
<Grid  x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid  Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Name="lbLista">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                Background="White">

                            <TextBlock x:Name="Curso" Text="{Binding Curso}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"/>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="Periodo" Text="{Binding Periodo}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Turno" Text="{Binding Turno}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Semestre" Text="{Binding Semestre}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I need to read the values from all TextBlocks,but i can't access because those are inside DataTemplate, and I want to know how can I separate each items with different strings like this!

```
string Curso = CursoNameFromList;
```

Comment: The required data can be selected from the result itself. Why do we need to access the `ListBox`? `var CursoList = e.Result.Select(i => i.Curso)`

Comment: @Bells Look, i want to put this Curso inside of one string,how to do ?

Comment: @Bells i try to use BreakPoints and that's what i got! [Image](http://s9.postimg.org/cmkymzmlr/image.png) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.Result.Select(i => i.Curso)` will return the `IEnumerable` type. You can form the string using `string.join`. 
In short -

```
string Curso = string.join(",", e.Result.Select(i => i.Curso))
```

Comment: Thank you a LOT!! i really need this!